# After applying for a position directly with the company, should I still send a message to the recruiter on LinkedIn?

Tags: job-search, recruitment, linkedin

A recruiter accepted my LinkedIn personal connection request.  I put a message there telling him how interested I am in working for the company and how my skills will be a great fit for the position.

He accepted my connection request which allows me to message him directly (If I view my messages on LinkedIn it has an option to send him a message).  I have already applied for the position to the generic HR@domainname email address, should I still send my CV directly to the recruiter on LinkedIn via message to reinforce my interest in the position?

Edit: To clarify, I have only sent my CV to the HR general email address, not the recruiter via LinkedIn yet.

Answer (score 2):

> should I still send my CV directly to the recruiter on LinkedIn via message to reinforce my interest in the position?

You say you already conveyed to the recruiter your interest on the company and how you can bring benefit to the company, plus you already sent the CV to them... Stating the same thing again and sending the CV again would be unnecessary and redundant, and could be perceived as insistent or needy.

I suggest you don't write again, unless you feel *really* compelled to do so. Nor do I suggest sending the CV again, as that would result in a duplicate CV that they will have to go over (basically, wasting their time).

Now, what's left is to wait for the application process to move forward, and see if this specific application yields an interview.

Meanwhile, keep your options open and continue job-hunting and applying to other companies you are interested in.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! To clarify, when I sent my LinkedIn connection request, it was just very short text stating that I have interest in the position and how my skills were a great match (no CV enclosed).  I had only sent my CV to the generic HR email address (as per the application instructions on the website) which forwards to all the recruiters email addresses.

Answer (score 0):

When job hunting, try to strike a balance between being too nice and being too needy. It seems to me, you are currently erring on the "nice" side. It's okay to be demanding!

In general, you may benefit from a recruiter making your case for you and giving feedback on your CV.
But I believe you are not looking at the correct path here. The recruiter will not do anything for you, because he gets paid for each successful referral. A candidate the company already has contact info for is not a referral.

So, my proposal:

- Call the HR department (no, don't send an email, though it requires less courage) and *politely* inquire whether they have received your application, whether there are any questions, and when you can expect to get feedback. And if the person on the other end of the line seems to be in a chatty mood, it's okay to ask some questions about the company and tell them that you like their vision, products, whatever. Don't do that if it sounds like you are stealing their time, though!
- More general: Don't pile all your hopes on one application! This will make you more relaxed. And it's also good to not have your first interview at the one place you desperately want to go - gather some experience!